# WHMCS: how to check the cart for an AU domain?

Tags: whmcs

I'd like to add a message to the `configure domains` screen to check if any AU domains have been added to the cart, and if so, advise the customer they need an Australian Business Number to buy the domain.

I believe I need to check the `$domains` array, but I can't find any mention of this array at `https://developers.whmcs.com`

What code would I need to add to my `configure-domains.tpl` file to check for an AU domain in the cart and display a message?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily in the `$domains` loop in your `configuredomains.tpl` by exploding the domain name by `.` and check if the extension is `au`, then show custom message, like this:

```
{foreach $domains as $num => $domain}
    {assign var=extention value="."|explode:$domain.domain}

    {if isset($extention[1]) && $extention[1] == 'au'}
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
            <p>Since you have added an "au" domain, you need an Australian Business Number to buy the domain.</p>
        </div>
    {/if}
```

Instead of adding a static text here, you can add translated text in the `lang` files and print it here like:

```
<p>{$LANG.aucartmsg}</p>
```